# How to download base64 file from remote api by vue-router link?

Tags: vuejs2

I need to download files from remote api by `vue-router` link. Remote api returns files in `base64`.

I add route:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/files/:id', name: 'file', component: Vue.component('vue-file'), props: true }
    ],
});
```

and add component for it:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'file',
        props: {
            id: String
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.download();
        },
        methods: {
            download: function() {
                let $this = this;

                axios
                    .get('apiurl' + encodeURIComponent(this.id))
                    .then(function (response) {
                        download(response.data.base64content)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works but I don't want to show component template `<template><div></div></template>`. I even don't want to refresh the content on the screen. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. Vue Components were done for rendering. Your implementation would be nicer as a mixin or plugin, if you don't want to render anything.
Although, I think you can do something like:

```
render() {
   return null;
},
```